# How can django-cms plugins be displayed using pagination

Tags: django, plugins, pagination, django-cms

I written two django-cms plugins to display image galleries and videos.

These are attached to CMS pages at `/gallery/` and `/videos/` where each template has a placeholder allowing the corresponding plugin to be included.

At that base level where I have `gallery.html` and `video.html` rendering all plugin instances to the page I would like to be able to attach `endless` for pagination.

This was a really simple task to achive pagination on images within a gallery because I have an `apphook` view in the `gallery` to collect a list of all the images and then it's as simple as `{% pagingate images %} {% for image in images %}` etc in the template.

However in a template where django-cms controls the collection & rendering of all the plugin instances and I lose that control, how can I paginate the plugins?

I've started down a route of using an `apphook` on the `/gallery/` index, but to acomplish this I can imagine I'll need to stop django-cms doing what it does by default and what it should be left to do. So I need some guidance/advise on the best method for the job. Anyway, here's some code;

```
# views.py
    def gallery_index(request, *args, **kwargs):

        template = request.current_page.template
        placeholder_id = request.current_page.placeholders.get(slot='gallery').id

        gallery = Placeholder.objects.get(id=placeholder_id)
        galleries = gallery.cmsplugin_set.all()

        return render_to_response(
            template,
            {'galleries': galleries},
            context_instance=RequestContext(request)
        )

# gallery.html
    <h3>GALLERIES</h3>

    <div id="panel-area" class="gallery_grid">
        <ul id="galleries" class="gridview" style="width: 800px;">
    {% paginate galleries %}
        {% for gallery in galleries %}
            <li>{{ gallery }}</li> <!-- testing the pagination -->
        {% endfor %}
    {% placeholder "gallery" %}
        </ul>
    {% show_pages %}

# cms_plugins.py
    class ImageGalleryPlugin(CMSPluginBase):

        name = _('Image Gallery')
        model = ImageGalleryPlugin
        form = ImageGalleryAdminForm
        render_template = 'single_gallery.html'

        def render(self, context, instance, placeholder):

            context.update({'gallery': instance,})        
            return context

# single_gallery.html
    <li class="gallery_top">
    <span class="title">
        <a href="{% url 'image_gallery_page' page_id=request.current_page.id gallery_id=gallery.id %}">{{ gallery.event_date|date:"d/m/Y" }}<br/>
             <p class="sub-text">View more of {{ gallery.event_name }}</p></a>
    </span>
        <img src="{{ gallery.display_random.gallery_display }}" alt="" border="0" />
    </li>
```

My current solution is a jQuery solution, but I'd love it all to be controlled by django endless pagination for consistency in behaviour and design.

Comment: django.contrib.pagination necessarily requires access to GET vars like "page" on the URL. Because of this, doing pagination in the context of a djangoCMS plugin is ill advised: what if your user installed two paginated plugins on the same page? What if the primary content (non-plugin) on the page is paginated? Confusion will ensue! You could override the GET var names on a per-plugin basis, I suppose, but this still won't help if your user installs the same plugin more than once on the page.

Comment: If you wish to do this with a CMS App, then this is great! Definitely read up on the subject here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/pagination/ Also, you should know that the Class Based Views system in Django has built-in support for pagination. Check it out here: http://ccbv.co.uk/projects/Django/1.6/django.views.generic.list/ListView/

Comment: Thanks @mkoistinen. I am happy to go with the 'its against the ideals of a plugin' way of thinking, but thought it'd be nice for it to be an option in the admin for the user if they wanted a lot of instances in one page (which is certainly possible for page of image gallieres).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Been there. Pagination in Django CMS plugin is indeed problematic.

**One possible way to solve the problem**

1. Implement paginated API endpoint for fetching the objects. Use `django.views.generic.list.ListView` for example. It has nice built in pagination.
2. In CMS plugin, fetch objects from the API endpoint with AJAX. CMS plugin doesn't need to know which objects to render, it just needs to know where it can fetch the objects (the API endpoint).

This approach requires frontend code for fetching the correct objects, updating the UI, keeping track of the current page and so on, but can be (and has been) successfully used to implement paginated Django CMS plugins.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my quick solution to add pagination into a django cms plugin

```
from cms.models.pagemodel import Page
from cms.plugin_base import CMSPluginBase
from django.http import Http404
from django.core.paginator import InvalidPage, Paginator


class MyPlugin(CMSPluginBase):

    def render(self, context, instance, placeholder):
        query_set = Page.objects.filter(is_page_type=False)
        page = context['request'].GET.get('page') or 1
        paginator, page, queryset, is_paginated = self.paginate_queryset(page, query_set, 6)
        context.update({'paginator': paginator,
                        'page_obj': page,
                        'is_paginated': is_paginated,
                        'object_list': queryset
                        })
        return context

    def paginate_queryset(self, page, queryset, page_size):
        paginator = Paginator(queryset, page_size)
        try:
            page_number = int(page)
        except ValueError:
            if page == 'last':
                page_number = paginator.num_pages
            else:
                raise Http404(_('Page is not “last”, nor can it be converted to an int.'))
        try:
            page = paginator.page(page_number)
            return (paginator, page, page.object_list, page.has_other_pages())
        except InvalidPage as e:
            raise Http404(_('Invalid page (%(page_number)s): %(message)s') % {
                'page_number': page_number,
                'message': str(e)
            })
```